# Where I could get Castle WCF facility version for Castle Windsor 2.5.2?

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, castle, wcffacility

I have researched, but cannot find it anywhere. Nuget package and latest source on GitHub are updated to work with Windsor 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official version of the facility for Windsor older than v3